# What are these weapons in My Adventures with Superman s1e7 "Kiss kiss fall in portal"?

Tags: superman, object-identification

Without getting to specific on spoilers, we see a rack of weapons and arms in My Adventures with Superman s1e7. I recognize a few of these, and from that I can assume most if not all reference different IPs.

All items are marked with a shelf and item number, I know that D10 is the sky hook from Bioshock Infinite, while B1 looks like the noisy cricket from men in black. The item on the top shelf marked with a red x is plot relevant to the series, so it doesn't need identification.

[High res version](https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2F445hl9w92lhb1.jpg)

[image]

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/TwoBestFriendsPlay/comments/15oacim/multiple_weapons_references_in_the_new_superman/